# How to make a Gatsby JS site GDPR compliant?

Tags: cookies, gatsby, privacy-policy

Is there any way to integrate the functionality related to GDPR into a Gatbsy JS website?
Cookiehub would be a great option, and there's even a plugin for it but this plugin does not seem to work as it should.
Here's the link to the plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-cookiehub
Do you have any other suggestion that I should look into?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All in all there isn't much that makes a Gatsby site different from a standpoint of the basics of online compliance (I've recently seen more and more people asking about this).
You can **link to or have a privacy policy page, terms of service if needed, and even for cookies** there are good options, too.
On that front I've recently [seen this iubenda Gatsby integration/plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-iubenda-cookie-footer/?=iubenda), that probably does more than you might have had in mind. You'll just integrate the iubenda options in your `gatsby-config.js`

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-iubenda-cookie-footer',
    options: {
      iubendaOptions: {"lang":"en","siteId":XXXXX,"cookiePolicyId":YYYYY, /* ... */ },
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I have privacy and cookie policy already, but I was searching for something that would allow me to display the cookie banner where the user can choose what kind of cookie to agree on (such as technical, marketing, etc.) while automatically blocking the others that remain unaccepted. I've checked out the iubenda plugin and it does seem to do something similar. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

For the Gatsby website, you could use a combination of [`gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/) for analytics configuration in your `gatsby-config.js` and [`react-cookie-consent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie-consent) to display the cookie banner.

```sh
# using npm
npm install --save gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies react-cookie-consent

# using yarn
yarn add gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies react-cookie-consent
```

You can find a more detailed tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860068/how-set-up-a-gatsby-cookie-consent-banner-with-gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies/59922277#59922277).